# How get all rows values into a string from datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I habe Datatable dt with one column "srlno" and i have data like

```
srlno
------
1
2
3
4
5
```

i want to get all rows values into string as 1,2,3,4,5 with out using any for loops. 
Please suggest best ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Linq to get array of string from `DataTable` column. Once you have string array you can use `string.Join` to convert it to comma separated strings.

```
string.Join(",", dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r=>r.Field<decimal>("srlno")).ToArray());
```

Comment: getting error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.String'. Column "srlno" in database is number

Comment: its working after a liitle change string.Join(",", dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r=>r.Field<decimal>("srlno")).ToArray());